# Selecting a column/property of an array which is inside another array Powershell

Tags: arrays, sql-server, powershell, multidimensional-array, collections

Original Table/collection ($clctionTbl)

```
Col1  Col2    Col3
1     test1   {A1,A2}
2     test2   {B}
3     test3   {C1,C2,C3}
4     test4   {D1,D2,D3,D4}
```

The `Col3` array/collection still has other properties such as

```
Status   Id
Active   A1
Retired  A2
```

I wanted to insert specific columns above into SQL via Powershell's `Data.SQLClient.SqlBulkCopy` 
Col1
Col2
Col3's Id column only.

I have tried directly adding rows to a DataTable but instead of the Data `Col3` is returned as the Type which is an `System.Collections.Generic.List`

I know I can manually type each property instead like

```
$Col1Val = $clctionTbl.Col1
$Col2Val = $clctionTbl.Col2
$Col3Val = $clctionTbl.Col3.Id
```

and manually insert(foreach) or add them to a datatable and then bulk insert it to a SQL table but

any ideas on how to get the desired output the better way? I was kinda hoping that there's a sub-select in powershell to get the Column of an inner array/collection.

Desired Output to be Inserted in SQL table

```
Col1  Col2     "Col3's Id column"
1     test1     A1,A2
2     test2     B
3     test3     C1,C2,C3
4     test4     ....
```

Comment: `$clctionTbl | Select Col1, Col2, @{Name="Col3ID"; Expression={$_.Col3 -join ','}}`

Comment: Thank you man!! This actually works. I didn't know I could join it like that. A slight modification though `Expression={$_.Col3.Id -join ','}}`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name im using MS SQL server EE, Col3 would be varchar(200) in my SQL table.